# How to access properties of JSON with Sequelize

Tags: jquery, json, sequelize.js

I have the following JSON User structure :

```
{
        "userId": 3,
        "username": null,
        "email": "helpdesk@chronos.com.ar",
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "status": "active",
        "businessCompanyId": null,
        "roles": [
            {
                "userRolesId": 95,
                "userId": 3,
                "role": "helpdesk"
            }
        ]
    },
```

And I'm trying to get all the users using Sequelize where 'role' property is equal to 'user' or 'business':

```
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await User.findAll({
      where: {
        roles: {
          [Op.or]: [
            { role: 'user' },
            { role: 'business' }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
    res.json(response);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

But I'm getting the following error at console: `Error: Invalid value { role: 'user' }`

Any idea how can I make this query work?

Comment: When you ask a question for Sequelize, could you add the tag of DB that you are using?  Sequelize syntax is often dependent on underlying DB, so it helps people to answer properly, if there is the DB tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `roles` is JSON field and it is **array**, you need to use JSON function to look up contents in the array.

First, `JSON_EXTRACT` to extract the value of `role` within the array (use wildcard to extract all roles).

Then `JSON_CONTAINS` to look up if the extracted roles contain "user" or "business".

```js
const response = await User.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            Sequelize.fn('JSON_CONTAINS', 
                Sequelize.fn('JSON_EXTRACT', Sequelize.col('roles'), Sequelize.literal('"$[*].role"')), 
                '"user"'),
            Sequelize.fn('JSON_CONTAINS', 
                Sequelize.fn('JSON_EXTRACT', Sequelize.col('roles'), Sequelize.literal('"$[*].role"')), 
                '"business"')
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer depends of your dialect. What are you using ? Postgres ? MySQL ? ... ?

In any case you have a relationship between 2 tables right ? User and Role.

If yes, you will be forced to try a solution using sequelize.fn & sequelize.col.

For ex, for Postgres I do:

```
const response = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      db.sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn('json_extract_path_text', db.sequelize.col('roles'), 'role'),
      Op.eq,
      'user'
      ),
      db.sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn('json_extract_path_text', db.sequelize.col('roles'), 'role'),
      Op.eq,
      'business'
      )
    ]
  }
});
```

Explaination:

- sequelize.where: produces a valid argument you can use as where or in a Op.and/Op.or. Its arguments are: attribute, comparator, value
- sequelize.fn: allows to call a DB function (depends of your dialect). Its arguments are: function_name, param1, param2, param3, ...
- sequelize.col: allows to get a column from a path (simple column or eager loading are supported)

Comment: Hi. In this case, the role is in the same table as User and I'm using MySQL dialect!

Comment: How can be Role in the same table as User ? MySQL does not have a "array" column type. Is it a JSON column ?